# File upload failure php

Tags: php

It keeps saying faI lure and I'm losing my mind I have tried every fix and Google search I can possible think of the name in the form is `file`

Here is my script sorry in advane for poor indenting I posted this on my phone

```
        <?
         if(isset ($_POST ['submit'])){
         $name = $_POST ['name'];
         $pub = $_POST ['author'];
         $price = $_POST ['price'];
         $size = $_POST ['size'];
         $icon = $_POST ['icon'];

           $fname = str_replace (" ", "", $name);
           $make = mkdir  ("/membri/deathcrow/0android/appmarket/appmarket/downloads/$fname");
           $dir = "/membri/deathcrow/0android/appmarket/appmarket/downloads/$fname";
           $source = "/membri/deathcrow/0android/appmarket/appmarket/downloads/$fname/$fname.apk";
          $file = $_FILES ["file"]["tmp_name"];
          $filen = $_FILES ["file"]["name"];
                   if(move_uploaded_file($file,"/membri/deathcrow/0android/appmarket/appmarket/downloads/ ". $fname . $filen)){
        /*$sql = "INSERT INTO appmarketapps SET name='$name', publisher='$pub', price='$price', picture='$icon', src='$source'";
             $query = mysql_query ($sql); */
             echo "<script>alert ('Success'); </script>";
              }else {
        echo "<script>alert ('Failure'); </script>";
              }
            }
            ?>
```

Here is the pertaining html

```
        <!-- form start -->
        <form method='post' role="form">
          <div class="box-body">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="appname">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" name='name' class="form-control" id="appname" placeholder="Enter App Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="publisher">Publisher:</label>
              <input type="text" name='author' class="form-control" id="publisher" placeholder="App Publisher">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="publisher">Price:</label>
              <input type="text" name='price' class="form-control" id="publisher" placeholder="App Price">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="size">Size:</label>
              <input type="text" name='size' class="form-control" id="size" placeholder="Size (KB, MB, GB)">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="icon">Icon:</label>
              <textarea name='icon' rows="5" cols="80" class="form-control" id="icon" placeholder="Icon..."></textarea>
            </div>
            <!-- select -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Select Category:</label>
              <select class="form-control" name='catagory'>
                <option>Games</option>
                <option>Utilities</option>
                <option>Applications</option>
                <option>System</option>
                <option>Other/Uncategorized</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fileupload">File upload</label>
              <input type="file" name='file' id="fileupload">

              <p class="help-block">Upload Application</p>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Is this an update?
            <p class="help-block">Only check this box if the file being uploaded is an update. (i.e. v0.2.1 --> v0.2.2)</p>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->

          <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" name='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- /.box -->
```

Comment: do you have the right permissions to write to that directory?

Comment: have you correctly set the `enctype` attribute of the form?

Comment: this issue come for write permission in your PC , change your save location to writable path .

Comment: Is **/membri/** folder at your root partition? If not, then create an absolute path .e.g **/var/www/<documentRoot>/membri/<remainingPath>**

Comment: Updated with the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `enctype` to `multipart/form-data` when uploading files, like this:

```
   <!-- form start -->
    <form method='post' role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
      <div class="box-body">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="appname">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name='name' class="form-control" id="appname" placeholder="Enter App Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="publisher">Publisher:</label>
          <input type="text" name='author' class="form-control" id="publisher" placeholder="App Publisher">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="publisher">Price:</label>
          <input type="text" name='price' class="form-control" id="publisher" placeholder="App Price">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="size">Size:</label>
          <input type="text" name='size' class="form-control" id="size" placeholder="Size (KB, MB, GB)">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="icon">Icon:</label>
          <textarea name='icon' rows="5" cols="80" class="form-control" id="icon" placeholder="Icon..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <!-- select -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Select Category:</label>
          <select class="form-control" name='catagory'>
            <option>Games</option>
            <option>Utilities</option>
            <option>Applications</option>
            <option>System</option>
            <option>Other/Uncategorized</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fileupload">File upload</label>
          <input type="file" name='file' id="fileupload">

          <p class="help-block">Upload Application</p>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> Is this an update?
        <p class="help-block">Only check this box if the file being uploaded is an update. (i.e. v0.2.1 --> v0.2.2)</p>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.box-body -->

      <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" name='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box -->



<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['author'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['size'], $_POST['icon'], $_FILES['file'] ) ){

         $name      = $_POST ['name'];
         $pub       = $_POST ['author'];
         $price     = $_POST ['price'];
         $size      = $_POST ['size'];
         $icon      = $_POST ['icon'];

         $file      = (object)$_FILES['file'];
         $ftmp      = $file->tmp_name;
         $fname     = $file->name;
         $fsize     = $file->size;
         $ferror    = $file->error;
         $ftype     = $file->type;



         if( is_uploaded_file( $ftmp ) && $ferror == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){

            $basepath   = '/membri/deathcrow/0android/appmarket/appmarket/downloads/';
            $filename   = str_replace( " ", "", $name );
            $dir        = $basepath . $filename;

            /* If the folder does not already exist, create it */
            if( !file_exists( $dir ) ) mkdir( $dir );
            clearstatcache();


            $source     = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "$filename.apk";
            $result     = @move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $source );

            if( $result ){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `appmarketapps` SET `name`='$name', `publisher`='$pub', `price`='$price', `picture`='$icon', `src`='$source';";
                echo $sql;
            } else {
                echo 'error: unable to move file';
            }

            exit( "<script>alert('".( $result ? 'success' : 'failure' )."')</script>" );
         } else {
            echo 'error: possible file upload attack or other error';
         }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Done now it's saying "success" and it creates the folder but the file isn't in the folder

Comment: Developing on my phone atm cause I'm on a business trip my laptops at home so Im not able to check

Comment: @RamRaider Nice. +1

Comment: Is this on a Windows server? `mkdir` will set a permission of `0777` by default - but not on windows so `chmod` should be used manually

Comment: It's an apache server

Comment: I mean - is it running on Windows rather than a *nix system?

Comment: Yes it's running on windows

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(move_uploaded_file($file,"/membri/deathcrow/0android/appmarket/appmarket/downloads/ ". $filen))
```

instead of

```
if(move_uploaded_file($file,"/membri/deathcrow/0android/appmarket/appmarket/downloads/ ". $fname . $filen))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have write permissions to that directory and make the permissions 777 for testing purposes but change it to what you need if it works. Please also post the html for us to have a clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

> > First of all check for file permission.
> >
> > And for directory source path where you want to store your uploaded file use *absolute path*. You can use `getcwd()` function to get absolute path.
> >
> > Remove whitespace from if statement where you use `move_uploaded_file` 
> >     Like

```
<?
    if(isset ($_POST ['submit'])){
        $name = $_POST ['name'];
        $pub = $_POST ['author'];
        $price = $_POST ['price'];
        $size = $_POST ['size'];
        $icon = $_POST ['icon'];

        $fname = str_replace (" ", "", $name);
        $make = mkdir("/membri/deathcrow/0android/appmarket/appmarket/downloads/$fname");
        $dir = "/membri/deathcrow/0android/appmarket/appmarket/downloads/$fname/";
        $source = "/membri/deathcrow/0android/appmarket/appmarket/downloads/$fname/$fname.apk";
        $file = $_FILES ["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $filen = $_FILES ["file"]["name"];
        if(move_uploaded_file($file,"/membri/deathcrow/0android/appmarket/appmarket/downloads/". $fname . $filen)){
            /*$sql = "INSERT INTO appmarketapps SET name='$name', publisher='$pub', price='$price', picture='$icon', src='$source'";
            $query = mysql_query ($sql); */
            echo "<script>alert ('Success'); </script>";
        }else {
            echo "<script>alert ('Failure'); </script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

also add form attribute `enctype= multipart/form-data` to upload a file

Comment: It's my personal server so yes I have permissions and I have file uploads on in php.ini

Comment: I did that as well look at my comment on ramraiders post

Comment: Oh I think I got the point...  `$dir = "/membri/deathcrow/0android/appmarket/appmarket/downloads/$fname/";`

Comment: You miss the `forward slash`

Comment: You create a folder with user name and you want to insert uploaded file in that folder so you need add forward slash at the end of your directory source.

Comment: Dir wasn't used I typed it directly so that wouldn't be the issue

Comment: Ok, @RamRaider made some changes in his post please check. And let me know if its help you ?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($file,"/membri/deathcrow/0android/appmarket/appmarket/downloads/". $fname .'/'. $filen)`